# Angular 17 Top-level await Error while using pdfjs-dist

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdfjs-dist

I'm using Pdfjs library and i'm facing this error

**Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome119.0", "edge119.0", "firefox115.0", "ios16.0", "safari16.0" + 7 overrides)**

**/******/ **webpack_exports** = globalThis.pdfjsLib = await (globalThis.pdfjsLibPromise = **webpack_exports**);**

I saw an issue at github saying that i can fix this with vite but i'm not using vite at all in my project..

This is my tsconfig file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

[Please check this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26507)

I tried to change the target in tsconfig from ES2022 to ESNext but nothing works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, I ended up downgrading pdfjs-dist to the latest 3 version

`npm i pdfjs-dist@3.11.174`

This works as I suppose it is before they changed the package to use top level await.

**Unsuccessful fix attempts**

I tried several other solutions which didn't work. The [Angular CLI issues](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26507) suggested editing vite.config.ts, which isn't actually accessible. This is also referenced in [pdf.js issues](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/17245).

I also tried with the [vite-plugin-top-level-await](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-top-level-await) package, it did not work.

Comment: Thanks!, do you have any idea about an article or library that can help me with annotations ? i want to add highlight, stamps, draw ... etc